# generate series equivalent in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, date, generate-series

I have a query like this

```
SELECT DATE(date) AS DateOnly, COUNT(DISTINCT(device_id)) AS nrUnique 
FROM `mytable`
WHERE date>='2013-10-04 18:32:04' and date<now()
GROUP BY DateOnly 
order by DateOnly
```

result

```
2013-10-05 | 10
2013-10-08 | 5
```

I want to generate a result like this

```
2013-10-04 | 0
2013-10-05 | 10
2013-10-06 | 0
2013-10-07 | 0
2013-10-08 | 5
```

I've do this in postgresql using a union like this

```
....
UNION
(SELECT 0 as count, date(generate_series('2013-10-04 18:32:04'::date, now(),'1 day')) as timestamp))
```

How I can do this with MYSQL?

Comment: In MySQL you will need to create and populate a table containing all possible dates in order to do this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'm pretty sure you can fake it in MySQL using variables, see the two duplicates at the top of the **Related** list.

Comment: @muistooshort you still need a donor table to do that. And although any table would do this method ain't too reliable.